# Build graph given coordinates of adjacent nodes

Tags: java, graph

The way you can interpret this is as such:

```
nodeName
nodeName's x-coord, nodeName's y-coord
x-coord of an adjacent node, y-coord of that adjacent node
```

...and the rest are just more coordinates of adjacent nodes. I'm trying to figure out how to store this as a graph so I can check if a path is legal. For example, maybe nodeA-nodeB-nodeC is legal, but nodeA-nodeC-nodeD is not.

So, my final question is: what is the best way to code the Graph class, and populate it by reading in this data?

Comment: What do you mean by path being "legal"?

Comment: @AlexeyBerezkin Well an illegal path would be one that can't be reached by going from one node to another by the adjacencies specified in the data

Comment: @AlexeyBerezkin For example, in the data above, you can go from node A to the node with coords (2,1), but you can't go to the node with coords (3,3)

Comment: Storing neighbors for each node is a good choice, I think. E.g. you can use `Map<Node, List<Node>>` for this.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Good to hear. But the problem still remains of how to read in the data... which I'm a little lost on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split file to groups of lines. Each group describes node. And then parse all groups.

```
Map<Node, List<Node>> neighbors;
Map<String, Node> nodeByCoords;

// Get node by it's coordinates. Create new node, if it doesn't exist.
Node getNode(String coords) {
    String[] crds = coords.split(" ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(crds[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(crds[1]);
    String key = x + " " + y;
    if (!nodeByCoords.containsKey(key)) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.setX(x);
        node.setY(y);
        nodeByCoords.put(key, node);
        neighbords.put(node, new ArrayList<Node>());
    }
    return nodeByCoords.get(key);
}

// Create node (if not exists) and add neighbors.
void List<String> readNode(List<String> description) {
    Node node = getNode(description.get(1));
    node.setName(description.get(0));

    for (int i = 2; i < description.size(); i++) {
        Node neighbor = getNode(description.get(i));
        neighbors.get(node).add(neighbor);
    }
}

// Splits lines to groups. Each group describes particular node.
List<List<String>> splitLinesByGroups (String filename) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    List<List<String>> groups = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> group = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (reader.ready()) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt())) {
            groups.add(group);
            group = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        group.add(line);
    }
    groups.add(group);
    return groups;
}

// Read file, split it to groups and read nodes from groups.
void readGraph(String filename) {
    List<List<String>> groups = splitLineByGroups(filename);
    for (List<String> group: groups) {
        readNode(group);
    }
}
```

Comment: I should also note that I decided to make a Node class where each Node stores his neighbors, but what Nikita did works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to store nodes somehow to find out whether the path is legal: you can check the legalty of the next node when reading them. The next node is legal if and only if it's coordinates differ to previous ones by no more than 1.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think repeatedly reading the file to find out what each node's coords and adjacencies is a necessarily efficient way to solve this. What if I have a whole bunch of paths which I want to test? Like nodeA-nodeC-nodeD, nodeE-nodeF-nodeG, etc..

Comment: I think you can store your nodes in any ordered fashion (ArrayList, LinkedList etc). Then, iterating over list nodes, you check whether the next node coordinates are legal.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/)

You could just create an instance of the [`SimpleGraph`](http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/graph/SimpleGraph.html) and populate it with nodes and edges:

```
// Define your node, override 'equals' and 'hashCode'
public class Node {

  public int x, y;

  Node (int _x, int _y) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
  }

  @Override public boolean equals (Object other) {
    if ( (other.x == x)
         && (other.y == y))
      return true;

    return false;
  }

  /* Override hashCode also */
}

// Later on, you just add edges and vertices to your graph
SimpleGraph<Node,Edge> sg;
sg.addEdge (...);
sg.addVertex (...);
```

Finally, you can use [`DijkstraShortestPath`](http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/DijkstraShortestPath.html) to find whether or not a path exists: